# Google page index - java

Tags: java, seo

does any one has idea how to get google page index in Java?
I was googleing since last 2-3 days but helpless, can any one refer me API for that or give some suggestion for how to do that

Lots of thanks in advance

[image]

For example if we search for facebook in google, we get around 22,980,000,000 results. So I want to fetch this number using JAVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a corresponding HTTP request from Java to Google, then parse the replied HTML code. There is a div with the ID `resultStats`. This div contains the number of results.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your real requirement is, what kind of index do you want? Google export fairly a bit amount of APIs via RESTful service, some of them are packaged with JavaScript lib like Google MAP API. There are also [Java client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth) for OAUTH authentication

The custom search API information could be found at http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html. A comprehensive list of google APIs could be accessed at https://code.google.com/apis/console